# Column visibility toggle buttons for two groups outside of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My DataTable is making use of [Visibility toggle buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columnsToggle.html) and everything is working fine, however I would like to "categorize" my columns and buttons, please see below.

[image: example]

We have five columns in total, and at the left we have a sidebar with categories Vegetable and Fruits. The issue here is that I can't seem to categorize the buttons, DataTables is using some default option

```
buttons: [
    'columnsToggle'   
],
```

Which means I can't separate the buttons into Fruits and Vegetables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by assigning different classes to `th` elements in the header, for example `group1` for fruits and `group2` for vegetables.

Then use the code below to create two sets of column visibility buttons and insert them into appropriate button containers.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();   

    var buttons1 = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'columnsToggle',
                columns: '.group1'
            }, 
        ]
    }).container().appendTo($('#buttons-group1'));

    var buttons2 = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'columnsToggle',
                columns: '.group2'
            }, 
        ]
    }).container().appendTo($('#buttons-group2'));
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/dys6jxof/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: @Dineshcoffee, you could mark the answer as accepted (by clicking on the check mark), it might help future readers.